# Special Group by & SUM

Tags: sql

I have a table with the following fields:
`ID, S, W` and data Like:

```
1,s1,w1
1,s2,w1
1,s3,w2
2,s4,w2
```

I would like to calculate SUM of S for each Id only for W = w1 and zero as result for other ID that don't have any data for w1.  for this example I have to get

```
1, s1+s2, w1
2, 0, null or 0
```

which means if Id has w1 show only this some,but if Id=2 has only W different of w1 show it as well. 
I tried

`SUM(CASE W = w1 THEN S ELSE 0 END) AS S GROUP BY ID, W`
but don't how to show also W? I hope i was clear is part of a UDF with a lot of other tables involved.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does  the following work for you?

```
Select id, SUM(CASE W = w1 THEN S ELSE 0 END) over(Partition by id order by 1) total, W from yourtable
```

Comment: How should I make partition to get rid off 1, s3? I think your solution should work if I can apply on my real code. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

Can"t you have a second Case statement ? Like CASE WHEN W = w1 THEN W ELSE 0 END as W ?

Comment: it doesn't remove the 1, 0 W2. If I add When W = w1 I loose the 2,0

Answer (score 1):

If I understood you correctly, you want:

```
SELECT  ID,
        SUM(CASE WHEN W = 'w1' THEN S ELSE 0 END) AS S,
        CASE WHEN W = 'w1' THEN W ELSE 0 END AS W
FROM YourTable
GROUP BY ID,
         CASE WHEN W = 'w1' THEN W ELSE 0 END
```